# How To Show 320x100 AdSense Ad Only On Mobile In a Responsive Site

Tags: adsense

I have created a 320x100 ad code in AdSense. I want to use it only on mobile, but when I add this code, it also appears on my desktop page as 320x100.

How can I make sure it only shows in mobile devices (not on tablets and desktop)?

Thanks.

```
<style>
.test { width: 320px; height: 100px; }
@media(min-width: 401px)  { .test { display:none; } }
</style>
<script asyncsrc="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js</script>
<!-- test -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxx"
data-ad-slot="xxxx"></ins>
<script>
```

(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});